# How to get count of 'li' elements list with selenium webdriver?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, selenium2

I have a list of li elements wrapped in sub-menu class of HTML, before clicking on any of the li element I wanted to cross check all li elements are present with `getText()` and `length` but not sure how to go with `length` as I don't see any suggestion to go for length.

```
    WebElement menuList =  driver.findElement(By.id("menu-item-33"));
    menuList.click();
    List<WebElement>elems = driver.findElements(By.className("sub-menu"));
      for (WebElement ddlList : elems)
      {
          System.out.println(ddlList.getText());
        //Something like ddlList.length(); but not able to work upon it.


          }
     }
```

Comment: `ddlList` is an individual element . . . if you just want to know how many you had, you want the length of `elems` . .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> There are two ways/solutions to print num of element.

**Solution 1 :**

```
int i=0;
for (WebElement ddlList : elems)
{
   System.out.println("Element Num "+ i +" is "+ ddlList.getText());
   i++;
}
```

- Here just increase value of `i` in each repetition.

**Solution 2 :**

```
for (int i=0; i < elems.size(); i++)
{
   System.out.println("Element Num "+ i +" is " + elems.get(i).getText());
}
```

- Here simple java loop with `size()` of list.

---

**If you want to print only num of elements then follow below :**

```
System.out.println(elems.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you found the answer. But I would like to share this line of code just in case if this could also add to help. This is a C# code

```
MyTickets = driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("#support-dashboard-form>div>div.dashboard-container>div")).Count();
    for (int i=2;i<=MyTickets+1;i++)
            {
                string TicketRef = driver.FindElement(By.CssSelector("#support-dashboard-form>div>div.dashboard-container>div:nth-child(" + i + ")>div.column.dashboard-column-icon>div.ticket-ref")).Text;
}
```