# How to get list of li elements using Selenium correctly?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, java

I'm using `Selenium` in the following manner as below:

```
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
        /*options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");*/
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();

        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
        driver.get("https://gearbest.net/");
        WebElement ulElement = driver
                .findElement(By
                        .cssSelector("body > div:nth-child(18) > div > div > div > div.tablets_content.clean > div > ul"));
        List<WebElement> liElements = ulElement.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
        //List<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<>();

        //try {
            /*org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://gearbest.net/products/").userAgent("Opera").get();
            Elements liElements = doc
                    .select("#main > div.default_products_list.default_products_list1 > div.themes_plist_right > div");*/

            // class of the whole element
            liElements.forEach(liElement -> {
                String str = ""; // this line for debugging purposes, it's redundant if we speak about production code
...
```

I have the problem while debugging with getting `li` elements because of [incorrect data](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/3ab1eb25aaa0497111dd78aff824ee4c#file-code-snippet-L21).

I suppose it happens because of some missing things.

[image]

I'm ready to provide more information per your
requirements, if you need.

Previously, I did it using `Jsoup` as a tool:

```
            org.jsoup.nodes.Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://gearbest.net/products/").userAgent("Opera").get();
            Elements liElements = doc
                    .select("#main > div.default_products_list.default_products_list1 > div.themes_plist_right > div");
```

But, as for now, it doesn't work because of updated version of the website, unfortunately.

I have already checked another similar question, but it doesn't look as my current [use case](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/a/26247/34920).

If I find the way how to realize it, I'll answer on my own question.

I'm attaching additionally for you, as well, [HTML](https://gist.github.com/invzbl3/717f0c1c4086300e0b2db4e9758be93d#file-html-page-L1132) for the current question.

Thank you for your attention :)

Comment: Could you please add the relevant HTML? It's possible there's a better and more accurate selector than the one you are using and that might be the problem.

Comment: @KatePaulk, yes, sure, I'll update now my question :)